# What does ‘favorited’ mean in searchTwitter results?

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping

For this query using R’s `twitterR::searchTwitter`:

```
search_t <- searchTwitter("#netanyahu", n = 1000, since = '2015-09-13')
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(search_t, as.data.frame))
View(df[, c('text', 'created', 'favoriteCount', 'retweetCount', 'favorited', 'retweeted', 'isRetweet')])
```

… I get the following results:

[image: twitteR results]

What does `favorited` column mean? It obviously doesn’t mean that since tweet has been favorited, since it’s been done so 6 times. I also went on Twitter and favorited that particular tweet and then re-ran the query. It still shows `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

From the twitter api overview: Object tweets link [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets)

> Favorited: Nullable. Perspectival. Indicates whether this Tweet has been favorited by the authenticating user.